# What are the minimum Firestore indexes needed for multiple fields?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I remember reading documentation about this but can't find the page anymore. Assume I have a document with 3 fields that are all queried on (the query can be any combination of these fields).

```
<document>
    identifier: string
    birthday: string
    cluster: [string] // string array
```

If I remember what I read correctly, I don't need to create a separate index for each combination, such as:

```
identifier, birthday, cluster
identifier, birthday
identifier, cluster
birthday, cluster
```

I can omit one or more of these. But since I can't find the document, I don't know if anything has changed. I normally use the link generated by the debugger console to create indexes but I'd like to understand how nesting them manually works, especially when there are more fields than just 3. So for this document, what are the minimum indexes I must create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called index merging, which is a way to take advantage of existing composite indexes to implicitly create larger composite indexes. For instance, if you had the following composite indexes:

```
identifier, birthday
cluster, birthday
```

You wouldn't need to create the following composite index since they exist in pieces on their own:

```
identifier, birthday, cluster
```

Therefore, of the 4 possibilities in your question, you would only need the last 3 (omitting the first index `identifier, birthday, cluster`)... *maybe*. Indexing can become not fun quickly. I've created composite indexes manually before and had all of my combinations covered but still got composite-index errors. When I opened the auto-gen link, it had the same composite index that I already created but the order of the fields was different. When I recreated the composite index manually with the different order, the query worked. I don't know if this behavior is intentional or not but I've since relied on auto-generating composite indexes because of that quirky experience.

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/concepts/index-overview#taking_advantage_of_index_merging

Answer (score 0):

> But since I can't find the document, I don't know if anything has changed.

Nothing has changed. If you perform a query, and there are no documents in the resulting QuerySnapshot, then there are definitely no documents that match your filters.

If your query needs an index [for whatever reason](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing), the query will fail with an error message saying what sort of index needs to be created, along with a link to the console to create it.  *The query will not silently fail.*

Without seeing the data in the database and your specific query parameters, there's not much that can be prescribed as a fix.  But if you don't get an error, then you don't need an index.  They key here is to always check for and log query errors so you can know for sure what needs to happen.